# Search function that is returning more results than expected. (Substring in string)

Tags: string, search, substring

The following code is for a Wikipedia-like page, the function is trying to find partial matches using a substring of the title for each md file. The problem is that is returning more results than expected. For example, if I type something gibberish such as 'iofdsm' it still returns matches.

```
def search_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searchQuery = request.POST.get('q')
        fetchEntry = util.get_entry(searchQuery)
          if fetchEntry == None:
            entries = util.list_entries()
            print(entries)
            print(searchQuery)
            queryMatches = []
            for i in searchQuery:
                for j in entries:
                    if(j.find(i) != -1 and j not in queryMatches):
                        queryMatches.append(j)
            print(queryMatches)          
            if len(queryMatches) >= 1:
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/search-page.html", {
                    "entries": queryMatches
                    })
            else:
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/404PageNotFound.html")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/{searchQuery}")
```

Variable `entries` prints `['CSS', 'Django', 'Git', 'HTML', 'Python']`

Variable `searchQuery` (gibberish as a test) is `bnfuiewbfuibewfuiw`

Variable `queryMatches` is `['Django', 'Python', 'Git']`
The expected `queryMatches` result should be `Not Found (empty list [])`.

I tried all three solutions as suggested in [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-filter-list-of-strings-based-on-the-substring-list/). These solutions work, but not as I intended, so they need refining to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the for loop that is iterating through each character in the `searchQuery` string and checking if it is a substring of any of the entries in the list. This will always return a match because every entry in the list will contain at least one character that is in the `searchQuery` string.

To fix this issue, update the for loop to only check if the entire `searchQuery` string is a substring of any of the entries in the list, like this:

```
for j in entries:
    if searchQuery in j:
        queryMatches.append(j)
```

This approach gives the expected behavior, where only entries that contain the entire `searchQuery` string as a substring will be added to the `queryMatches` list.